# How to use a css selector wildcard if the id values keep changing

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

**How to use a css selector wildcard if the id values keep changing**?

```
 <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title="**Edit**&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Copy</a" aria-describedby="list4_action"><a href="mac1/notification/edit?id=**12374**">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/mac1/notification/copy?id=12374">Copy</a></td>
```

This is in a table where the id # 12374 changes for every new row . I was looking for selenium to click the EDIT button .

When i use `cssSelector:a[href*='/mac1/notication/edit?$id='*]` the test is failing with the message

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector a[href*='/mac/notication/edit?$id='*] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
>   InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: Am I correct that you have multiple "Edit" links on the same page?  If so, you need to provide a more specific selector.  Please show the code where you are using the selector.

Comment: Yes, its a table and every row has a edit link . Each of the edit links have its unique id. I have a file where i have declared all the properties of the file in the  format=> <name of element>=<identifier>:<value>. I'm calling them in the code .

Comment: public void EditAlertSaveAndPublish(String publishOption, String alertType, String contactList, String contactEmail) throws Exception {

        //clickButton("alert.create.button");
        //this is temporary. Only happens in firefox.
        if (checkIfPopUpPresent()) {
            acceptPopUp();
            switchToActiveElement();
        }

        clickButton("button.edit");

Comment: @JeffC I posted the query after trying out a couple of things. I have automated most part except that this part of the application .

Comment: I don't know what your 'clickButton' method does, but I assume from your comments that it is translating "button.edit" into the cssSelector you reference.  If 'clickButton' is using something like the python method "find_element_by_css_selector" (you didn't tell us the language you're using either), the problem is that it finds more than one, and will choke.  Use the method that will find all of them (then you'll have to filter the list for yours), or change the selector to include your unique id.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in using the [CSS3 [attribute*=value] Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp).

However, you have a typo in your CSS Selector (you spelled notification wrong) and you've included an unnecessary `$` character. Try this:

```
a[href*='/mac1/notification/edit?id=']
```

Essentially, this CSS Selector will search for an `<a>` tag with an `href` attribute containing the string `/mac1/notification/edit?id=`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this did not work either . I used button.edit=cssSelector:a[href*='/mac/notication/edit?$id=']

Comment: Did you copy and paste my CSS selector correctly? And can you confirm your sample HTML is correct?

Comment: <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title="Edit&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Copy</a" aria-describedby="list4_action"><a href="/mac1/notification/edit?id=12374">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/mac1/notification/copy?id=12374">Copy</a></td>

Comment: When you use the CSS selector I've provided, what error do you receive?

Comment: *** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=a[href*='/mac1/notication/edit?id=']}...
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[href*='/mac1/notication/edit?id=']"}

Comment: Seriously? Re-read my answer. Please copy and paste the CSS selector and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following CSS selector,

```
a[href^='/mac1/notification/edit?id=']
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your recommendation. But I continue to get the error  : "Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[href^='/mac1/notication/edit?$id']"}

Comment: Sorry there was typo error. Please try with updated answer.

Comment: button.edit=cssSelector:a[href^='/mac1/notication/edit?'] ==> This is what you have indicated right.

Comment: I now see a "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 " and in addition the "Edit" button does not get clicked.

Comment: The failure is in the line that calls button.edit The line of code is   .....   clickButton("button.edit");

Comment: @vshwekharni You haven't posted any of your code so we can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

This was a little tricky as the UI page and table were coded differently.

Hence had look for the value of the JQGrid since it is a table. Then check for the value 'Edit' in the table and the pass the Click id. The id I was using was the correct one except that just using that id was not working.

The id that was used was alert.edit=cssSelector:a[href*='/mac1/Notification/edit?id=']

Comment: I gave you this exact [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44931847/4607317) two weeks ago...

Comment: Yes you are right  @Bᴜᴅɪ , though I did pass the exact same ID it did not work directly, so had to dig around a little bit.